# Dictionary to autocompletebox windows phone C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, dictionary

i got a dictionary:

`Dictionary<string, string> d = new Dictionary<string, string>();`

and i put them in a `AutoCompleteBox`:

`autobox.ItemsSource = d;`

displaying only the the key.

```
<toolkit:AutoCompleteBox x:Name="autobox" ValueMemberPath="Key" >
     <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" Tap="Item_Tap" />
           </DataTemplate>
     </toolkit:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
</toolkit:AutoCompleteBox>
```

Now i am trying to use item tap that when i press on the results its corresponding pair will display in a `MessageBox`.

```
private void Item_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
     var s = sender as TextBlock;
     Messagebox.Show(d[s.Text]);            
}
```

But when i click a result nothing will come out. Where did i go wrong?

thanks for helping

Comment: is your event Item_Tap even hit?

Comment: it works with my list box, but i guess item tap isn't appropriate for auto complete box.

Comment: TextBlock_MouseEnter i this is one of the appropriate event of my problem. i got it working already. thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

Try to make own model of element and bind to list of this elements. In this model create method OnTap or something like that and bind Tap to this method with EventToCommand.